# Install macOS onto external drive without rebooting

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, install, external-disk

Do you know if there is a way to install macOS onto an external drive without having to reboot the computer or go into recovery mode?

If this is not possible, is there a way to install macOS in recovery mode but stop the computer from restarting?

A lot of the methods used to install require recovery mode and also automatically restart the computer once the installer files have been loaded.

Thanks for your help

**Edit**

..Because I want to distribute macOS to a large number of SSD's as quickly as possible

Comment: This feels like it's really missing a "…because…"

Comment: I have never met **ANY** O/S (Mac, Windows, Linux, BE, BSD, Solaris...) that *didn't* require a reboot.

Comment: Your thinking of the standard user install methods.  There are a bunch of administrative tools to do installs. You can *install* all the Linux/Unix of the OSs you mention on an external drive without rebooting.  See clonzilla for instance: https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php Now, if you want to run the OS on the external drive, you need to reboot.

Comment: MajorFighter: There are a bunch of administrator tools to do what you describe. For an ordinary user like myself, I use carbon copy cloner. You can clone your startup drive to the external drive.  You could make of a reference drive which you can them clone to any drive you want.